Usage of SET statement in KQL
Can anyone help in understanding more about 'SET statement' in KQL?
I referred the documentation in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/set-statement?pivots=azuredataexplorer.
But I could not figure out on what situations should we use this, the examples provided here is not enough. Can someone provide more information or any realistic examples about when and where to use SET statement in KQL.

if you can't find a use case in which you need to use this feature, then you shouldn't use it. it doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong, on the contrary.
it's rarely required to use this feature, e.g. only in cases where the caller can't/won't set the request options in the dedicated 'client request properties' object, and wants/needs to set them within the text of the request.
